# How to use flatMapValues on Kafka

Tags: scala, apache-kafka-streams, flatmap

I am getting an error when using flatMapValues in Scala with Kafka library. Here is my code:

```
val builder: KStreamBuilder = new KStreamBuilder()
val textLines: KStream[String, String] = builder.stream("streams-plaintext-input")
import collection.JavaConverters.asJavaIterableConverter
val wordCounts: KTable[String, JLong] = textLines
  .flatMapValues(textLine => textLine.toLowerCase.split("\\W+").toIterable.asJava)
  .groupBy((_, word) => word)
  .count("word-counts")
```

and I am getting the error `missing parameter type` for `textLine` inside `flatMapValues`. If I replace for `flatMapValues((textLine: String) => textLine.toLowerCase.split("\\W+").toIterable.asJava)` it still does not work.

Anyone have some idea?
Thanks, Felipe

Comment: I guess, you need to specify the output types manually. Scala often cannot inver generics: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/faq.html#scala-compile-error-no-type-parameter-java-defined-trait-is-invariant-in-type-t

Comment: Try `flatMapValues{ case textLine: String => ... }`

Comment: it seems this is happening because Kafka was built in Java (https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/faq.html#scala-compile-error-no-type-parameter-java-defined-trait-is-invariant-in-type-t)

Comment: We hope to add a proper Scala API as soon as possible to get rid of those issues.

Comment: actually I solved the issue changing the scala version to 2.12.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working with Scala 2.12.4 I solved like this:

```
  val props = new Properties
  props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "streams-wordcount")
  props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092")
  props.put(StreamsConfig.KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String.getClass.getName)
  props.put(StreamsConfig.VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String.getClass.getName)

  val stringSerde: Serde[String] = Serdes.String()
  val longSerde: Serde[Long] = Serdes.Long()

  val builder = new StreamsBuilder()
  val textLines: KStream[String, String] = builder.stream("streams-plaintext-input")

  val topology: Topology = builder.build()

  println(topology.describe())

  val wordCounts: KTable[String, Long] = textLines
    .flatMapValues { textLine =>
      println(textLine)
      println(topology.describe())
      textLine.toLowerCase.split("\\W+").toIterable.asJava
    }
    .groupBy((_, word) => word)
    // this is a stateful computation config to the topology
    .count("word-counts")

  wordCounts.to(stringSerde, longSerde, "streams-wordcount-output")

  val streams = new KafkaStreams(topology, props)
  streams.start()
```